# django-ses setting error : Module "django_ses" does not define a "SESBackend" attribute/class

Tags: django, email, amazon-ses

I'm trying to **send email** using `django-ses` library and `Amazon SES`.

I did all essential settings following this(https://github.com/django-ses/django-ses, installing `boto and django-ses`, insult `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'` in my `settings.py`) but when I tried to send email.

I've got an error.

```
ImportError: Module "django_ses" does not define a "SESBackend" attribute/class
```

Is there any bugs in this `django-ses` library, or am I doing wrong something? I'm using **windows 10**, **python3**, and **django 1.11**

Comment: Were you able to get it to work with Celery?